# What type of programming structure can be used to enumerate classes?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a ray traced minecraft style voxel engine. I'm storing the level in a single 3d array at the moment where each value represents the type of voxel, e.g. 0 = air, 1 = stone, etc. Later the voxels will need to have certain properties, e.g. some might be textured, and certain actions may have to be performed when they're placed.

The first and most obvious solution I thought of was to have a base voxel class with methods such as OnPlace, etc. which will be derived from by the other types. But I'm not sure how to link this back to the map, I need a way which will be very fast (ray tracing is so slow) and flexible, but I have no idea. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).  It's fine to give each class an ID, which you can easily put in a public readonly property.  Then create a dictionary with the key being the ID and the value being the class type.  That way you can store the level efficiently and use the dictionary (fast but somewhat expensive in memory) to look up how each block should be rendered.

You'll need to use reflection and iterate through all the subclasses of your voxel base class when the program starts up to create the dictionary.

If you plan to support mods/plugins you'll need to be able to search more than your own assembly (the hardest part is getting a reference to their assembly, after that it's just recycled code) but for now just start with your own.

Comment: This all sounds very slow, I have to do this for every pixel multiple times, 30 times per second.  I'm not sure that's feasible on modern hardware.

Comment: You'll only need to create the dictionary **once**, at program startup.  Then when you are rendering for each pixel it's a rather quick lookup from the ID to the voxel subclass.  Reflection is rather slow, but since startup is a bit of a moot point when rendering that should be okay.

Comment: Since only one instance is needed of each voxel subclass, do you think it would be better to have the voxel subclasses as a singleton, then on startup load them all into an array based on their ID? Shouldn't that be faster as well

Comment: Actually yeah, I was figuring all your rendering information would be either static in the subclasses or you would have a single instance of it to get generic data from.  The array is a great idea that I feel really dumb for not thinking of.  I'm used to not using numbers so when I want association I use a dictionary but with numbers a direct array would work great.

Answer (score 3):

Obvious approach is to have 3d array of objects (of `class Voxel`) and have back reference with `location = {int x, int y, int z};`.

Note that it may be good idea to completely drop back reference from "voxel" to location so you don't need to use unique objects per cell. You can consider to use [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to share most of the date for similar "voxel" objects even if you still have to keep back reference to map.

Comment: I'm using an array of bytes at the moment, expanding to 16 bit integers is reasonable but 32 is not, unless I want to reduce the size of the map a lot.

Comment: I am biased towards `struct` for fast storage.

Comment: +1 same come in mind to me: flyweight and playn array with backreference.

Comment: Ok let's say I lose my mind and add 40,000 types of voxels, I could store that in 16 bits per voxel, I'm still wasting a massive 16 bits per voxel there. In reality it's much worse than that because I don't ever plan to have 40,000 types so I could be wasting as much as 24 bits per voxel.

Comment: 40K *types* (as in unique classes/structs) is indeed insane. Flywweight tries to solve exact problem of associating data with huge number of similar items (i.e. original sample in the book talks about associating data with characters of huge text). On other hand you seem to already set your mind on some particular approach and happy enough with it. I'm not exactly sure what help you are looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely what you're asking because when you say "enumerate classes" it makes me think of iterating over the objects properties using reflection; clearly that's not what you want to do.

To me, it sounds more like your 3D array should be holding objects rather than integers. If you have a `Voxel` base class which all voxels inherit from you remove the need for a type specifier. Instead you would just put abstract methods in the base class and override them in then the derived classes. Once you have all of that set up any code dealing with the array should be able to interact with it without knowing the type of the derived class.

Application code should just view it as an array of type `Voxel`. Calling methods on any given `Voxel` should execute the behavior specific to that type of voxel. That's kind of the basic idea of inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: I cannot afford to use 32 bits for each element in the map array due to memory restrictions.

Comment: @STRAIGHTOUTTACOMPTON if that's the case then your array can't even contain integers. What platform are you targeting? If that truly is a restriction I don't see how you can make it work at all... Is there going to be more memory consumed elsewhere? If you're really that hard up for memory you could make it a byte array and have each possible byte vale map to some static object. That would probably give you the smallest possible memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Ok man, your performance bottleneck isn't "selecting voxel type".  It's intersection and collision detection for the literally millions of rays (*at least* 1 per pixel, but you're not going to get good renders with only 1 ray per pixel) you need to trace at 60fps.

The only way to do such madness these days is with GPU ray tracing

- [rigidgems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YucC-1vtp-U)
- [These madebyevan examples](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-path-tracing/)

So your main concern isn't "what data structure to use" for determining voxel type.  It's efficient ray intersection code on the GPU.

NVIDIA has a ray tracing engine called [Optix](https://developer.nvidia.com/optix) at the moment.

Comment: I didn't say I had a performance bottleneck, I will if I have to do something slow everytime a ray hits something. My concern at the moment is how can I create that style of data structure which is flexible and fast, at the moment it'll run at decent speeds at 720p on the cpu.

Comment: What I'm saying is "resolving the voxel type" (whether its via pointer or integer) is going to be trivial in comparison to the number of _ray-box intersections_ you will need to do per frame (determining _which_ voxels got hit).

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the way you need to traverse the data for [rendering the voxels](http://hgpu.org/?p=7052). For rendering an [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) might be a nice solution (or perhaps a [K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree))

I suggest you first focus on what kind of access is needed (perhaps by testing) and then optimize.